# Gradle Sync Issue when I try to build and run code from a GitHub repository

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

**What I want to do**

I would like to execute a circle slider on Android app.

This is the reference of the circle slider which I would like to implement.

[HoloCircleSeekBar](https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar)

**Problem**

I have cloned the repository and tried to execute and see the code.

However, I can not build the files on my Android Studio.

Please give me advices to start emulator and see the function.

**Error Message**

Gradle Sync Issues:

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2.
Searched in the following locations:
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha2/gradle-2.2.0-alpha2.pom
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha2/gradle-2.2.0-alpha2.jar
Required by:
   :HoloCircleSeekBar-master:unspecified
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

**Development Environment**

Android Studio 3.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone updated this code but owner has not accept it. [https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar/pull/21/commits/5429211edaeabc68704999cecfe22974d336b85a](http://code%20commit%20Link) you can check this commit and update for yourself.